# Javascript/Jquery 3 way toggle show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do some 3 way toggling

The idea is to have 9 unique cases, that will come from combinations of my buttons.
We have 2 groups of buttons.
The combinations will display a box, and hide the others (we have one box for every case)

So cases would be:
1-1 /
1-2 /
1-3 /
2-1 /
2-2 /
2-3 /
3-3 /
3-4 /
3-5 /
3-6 /

I have done some code already, where I set variables and and hide/show boxes depending on the case, but I think I'm writing too much code and being inneficient.
This is what I have done so far... the part where I need help starts at line 80 of the javascript part

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGyMov

```
  $('#searchForCase').click(function() {
  if (case1 === true && case4 === true) {
    alert('case 1, Pessimistic  / Pessimistic ');
    //show box1
    $('.box1').show();
    $('.box2').hide();
    $('.box3').hide();
    $('.box4').hide();
    $('.box5').hide();
    $('.box6').hide();
    $('.box7').hide();
    $('.box8').hide();
    $('.box9').hide();
  } else if (case1 === true && case5 === true) {
    alert('case 2, Pessimistic  / neutral');
    //show box2, hide the others
    $('.box1').hide();
    $('.box2').show();
    $('.box3').hide();
    $('.box4').hide();
    $('.box5').hide();
    $('.box6').hide();
    $('.box7').hide();
    $('.box8').hide();
    $('.box9').hide();

  } else if (case1 === true && case6 === true) {
    alert('case 3, Pessimistic  / Optimistic');

  } else if (case2 === true && case4 === true) {
    alert('case 4, Neutral / Pessimistic');
  } else if (case2 === true && case5 === true) {
    alert('case 5, Neutral / Neutral');
  } else if (case2 === true && case6 === true) {
    alert('case 6, Neutral / Optimistic');

  } else if (case3 === true && case4 === true) {
    alert('case 7, Optimistic / Pessimistic');
  }
  else if (case3 === true && case5 === true) {
    alert('case 8, Optimistic / Neutral');
  }

  else if (case3 === true && case6 === true) {
    alert('case 9, Optimistic / Optimistic');
  }

   console.log('case 1 ' + case1);
   console.log('case 2 ' + case2);
   console.log('case 3 ' + case3);
   console.log('case 4 ' + case4);
   console.log('case 5 ' + case5);
   console.log('case 6 ' + case6);
    });
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing while writing less code?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not relate to bugfixing or problem solving. Refactoring working code is more likely to be accepted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Randy I'm not sure about conditions of code review, but a bad algorithm is able to define a problem as well. maybe he/she doesn't have complete knowledge about language features. I'm not sure indeed, just asking.

Comment: Why don't you do $('.box').hide() then $('.box2').show() etc. You seem to be repeating when its not necessary.

Comment: @mrReiha A bad algorithm is a problem indeed, but then I still think codereview is a better place. This exchange is meant for bugs and broken code, not improvements to working but lacking algorithms. If you have a performance problem and want to ask what algorithm to use, I would probably tell you to do some research about algorithms and maybe check here if your assumptions about the found algorithms are correct for the code you posted. Just providing code and asking for improvements shows too little research and effort imho.

Comment: @Randy couldn't agree more about **little research and effort**. by the way, do you think should I answer my opinion on this, or leave it for codereview community?

Comment: @mrReiha I've been told in no uncertain terms that code review is for working code only.  And you cannot ask them to review a specific part - they will review every aspect of the code and tell you about any and all ways to make it better - they said once I had asked about a specific problem with my working code, my question was bordering on being off topic: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6523/what-should-we-do-about-questions-asking-to-fix-warnings

Comment: I actually take this as a bug, since it's gonna impact a lot on the performance of this website, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @BlackLotus instead of hinding them like that - give them a shared class and hide them all before the ifs, then in the ifs just show the one you want - saves on a lot of selectors and code so that becomes more maintinable too

Comment: Agree with @Steve and Pete hide all before the first if statement and then show whatever box you need

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines will give an output about what the situation is. I'll try to keep it as simple as possible.

Before I start let me tell you this. You're using two different models for your switches. on `.switch` elements you have an `.active` class set when there's an active one, but on the other `.switch2` elements there's no such a thing. implement the second menu just like the first one.

First, you need to save those menu objects in an iterable way. and define a variable to save the situation.

```
var switch = document.querySelectorAll( '.switch' ),
    switch2 = document.querySelectorAll( '.switch2' ),

    output = '';
```

Then you need to run a loop on each of them to find the situation.

```
switch.forEach( function( v, i ) {

    if ( $( v ).hasClass( 'active' ) )
        output += ( i + 1 ).toString();

})

switch2.forEach( function( v, i ) {

    if ( $( v ).hasClass( 'active' ) )
        output += ( i + 1 ).toString();

})
```

*I've used jQuery because it's tagged in question. if it's not, there are many more options to take*.

Then you have an `output` variable like this:

```
console.log( output ); // '12'
```

which is one of your cases. now you can take this and use it any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of big changes you could do for better performance would be

- cache your boxes by putting them in a var - that way you are not always going to the dom to get them on every click
- hide all your boxes before the if and then you can only show the one you want in the if (this cuts down on code too for better maintainability)
- group your ifs - (optional) I think if you grouped your ifs, it would be a lot easier to understand what is going on in your code and therefore easier to maintain too

```js
var $boxes = $('.box'); // put them in a var here for better performance

$('#searchForCase').click(function() {

  $boxes.hide(); // hide all boxes first
  
  if (case1) { // all pessimistic for first selector
  
    if (case4) { // second option pessimistic
      alert('case 1, Pessimistic  / Pessimistic ');
      $boxes.filter('.box1').show();
    } else if (case5) { // second option neutral
      alert('case 2, Pessimistic  / neutral');
      $boxes.filter('.box2').show();
    } else if (case6) { // second option Optimistic
      alert('case 3, Pessimistic  / Optimistic');
      $boxes.filter('.box3').show();
    }
    
  } else if (case2) {// first selector all neutral 
  
    if (case4) { // second option pessimistic
      alert('case 4, neutral  / Pessimistic ');
      $boxes.filter('.box4').show();
    } else if (case5) { // second option neutral
      alert('case 5, neutral  / neutral');
      $boxes.filter('.box5').show();
    } else if (case6) { // second option Optimistic
      alert('case 6, neutral  / Optimistic');
      $boxes.filter('.box6').show();
    }
    
  } else if (case3) {// first selector all Optimistic 
  
    if (case4) { // second option pessimistic
      alert('case 7, Optimistic  / Pessimistic ');
      $boxes.filter('.box7').show();
    } else if (case5) { // second option neutral
      alert('case 8, Optimistic  / neutral');
      $boxes.filter('.box8').show();
    } else if (case6) { // second option Optimistic
      alert('case 9, Optimistic  / Optimistic');
      $boxes.filter('.box9').show();
    }
    
  }
});
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoKwdL)